# Spring Security + spring oauth2 resolution

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a new REST Server that I develop with spring. The Server must have only server side logic, nothing js or views.

At the moment I started with **Spring-boot version 1.2.7**, but this only to give a server to the front-end developers until the setup for the server is done.

After I will change to the **spring-core version 4.1** or something similar. 
At the moment I have difficulty in configure the security part.

At the beginning I started with a Java Config configuration but after I changed to xml, because I already had a similar configuration.

My end result must be these:

> **hostname **/api/auth**** :is the entry point where a frontend developer make a **POST** request with username and password of a customer. This call returns a token. This token permits me to identify the user the next time.
>
> hostname **/api/secure/resource/1** : is a resource that is protected, and can be accessible only with a valid token
>
> hostname **/api/other/1** : is an other type of resource that is not protected and can be accessible for everyone
>    hostname **/api/secure/bambi/**: is a resource that can be accessed from everyone but if it has a token then, more object-parameters are shown.

This seams for me a relative simple configuration, but I'm not able to configure it.
 I know that this is not very his work, but for handle the token, and the resource access I would use `OAUTH2` infrastructure (I'know, that this can be done better, but this was a requisite)

As follow I write you my configuration:

*StartUpApplication.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
@Import({ InMemoryDBConfigurationImpl.class})
@ImportResource({ "classpath:config/security-context.xml" })
public class SalustroApplication {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("InMemoryConfig")
private SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SalustroApplication.class);
    app.run(args);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean foo() {
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register(FooConfig.class);
    dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/");
    servletRegistrationBean.setName("foo");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

Do I need the foo method for the security part?

*security-context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<sec:http pattern="/api/auth" create-session="stateless" 
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/auth" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"
        access="isFullyAuthenticated() AND hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    <sec:headers />
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    c:decisionVoters-ref="votersList" />

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"       class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"
    p:realmName="p4me-test/client" p:typeName="Basic" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    p:filterProcessesUrl="/api/auth" />
<bean id="clientDetailsService"
    class="app.security.ClientDetailsServiceImpl" />
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService"
    c:clientDetailsService-ref="clientDetailsService" />

<bean id="clientDetailServiceImpl" class="app.security.ClientDetailsServiceImpl" />

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"
    p:realmName="p4me-test">
</bean>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="tokenEnhancer" class="app.security.CustomTokenEnhancer" />
<bean id="tokenServices" class="app.security.CustomTokenServices"
    p:tokenStore-ref="tokenStore" p:clientDetailsService-ref="clientDetailsService"
    p:supportRefreshToken="true" p:tokenEnhancer-ref="tokenEnhancer"
    p:accessTokenValiditySeconds="1800" />

<bean id="tokenStore"       class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemory TokenStore" />
    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="userAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
<bean id="userAuthenticationProvider"
    class="app.config.impl.security.SecureAuthenticationProvider"/>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService"
    token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler"
    token-endpoint-url="/api/auth">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler"
    p:tokenStore-ref="tokenStore" p:requestFactory-ref="requestFactory" />

<bean id="requestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory"
    c:clientDetailsService-ref="clientDetailServiceImpl" />

<util:list id="votersList">
    <bean class="app.security.AccessVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
        <property name="expressionHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</util:list>
```

*The test class*

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SalustroApplication.class)
public class AuthTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

@Test
public void find1() throws Exception {
    ResultActions doLogin = doLogin();
    String contentAsString = doLogin.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(contentAsString);

    DefaultMockMvcBuilder webAppContextSetup = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain);
    MockMvc build = webAppContextSetup.build();
    final ResultActions userResult = build.perform(post("/api/secure/user/1")
            .param("access_token", json.getString("access_token")).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print());

    assertEquals(someUser, userResult);


}

protected ResultActions doLogin() throws Exception {
    DefaultMockMvcBuilder webAppContextSetup = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain);
    MockMvc build = webAppContextSetup.build();

    final ResultActions loginResult = build.perform(post("/api/auth").param("grant_type", "password")
            .param("client_id", "testId").param("client_secret", "testSecret").param("username", "someUser")
            .param("password", "somePassword").param("scope", "read").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print());

    return loginResult;
}
```

}

*SecureAuthenticationPriver.class*

```
@Component
public class SecureAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

protected final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecureAuthenticationProvider.class);

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();

    GrantedAuthority authorithy = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER");
    grantedAuths.add(authorithy);

    UserEntity authenticatedUser = userPersistence.findByUserName(name, password);
    if (authenticatedUser != null) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
    } else
        return null;    }

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return false;
}
}
```

*AccessVoter.class*

```
@Service
public class AccessVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object> {
@Override
public boolean supports(final ConfigAttribute attribute) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(final Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public int vote(final Authentication authentication, final Object object,
        final Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
    final Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
    return 1;
}

private int refreshUserDetails(final Principal principal) {
    return 1;
}
}
```

*ClientDetailServiceImpl.class*

```
public class ClientDetailsServiceImpl implements ClientDetailsService {

@Override
public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(final String clientId) {
    if ("invalid".equals(clientId)) {
        throw new ClientRegistrationException(clientId + " not found");
    }
    return createClientDetails(clientId);
}

private ClientDetails createClientDetails(final String clientId) {
    final Set<GrantedAuthority> grantAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    grantAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

    final Set<String> authorizedGrantTypes = new HashSet<String>();
    authorizedGrantTypes.add("password");
    final BaseClientDetails details = new BaseClientDetails();
    details.setClientId("testId");
    details.setClientSecret("testSecret");
    details.setAuthorizedGrantTypes(authorizedGrantTypes);
    details.setAuthorities(grantAuthorities);
    return details;
}
}
```

*CustomTokenEnhancer.class*

```
@Component
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

private List<TokenEnhancer> delegates = Collections.emptyList();

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public void setTokenEnhancers(final List<TokenEnhancer> delegates) {
    this.delegates = delegates;
}

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    final DefaultOAuth2AccessToken tempResult = (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken;
    // tempResult.setAdditionalInformation(getAuthenticationMethod(authentication));
    OAuth2AccessToken result = tempResult;
    for (final TokenEnhancer enhancer : delegates) {
        result = enhancer.enhance(result, authentication);
    }
    return result;
}

private boolean isAdmin(final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    for (final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
        if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().compareTo("ROLE_ADMIN") == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

*CustomTokenServices.class*

```
public class CustomTokenServices extends DefaultTokenServices {

private TokenStore tokenStore;

private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

private TokenEnhancer accessTokenEnhancer;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(tokenStore, "tokenStore must be set");
}

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {

    final OAuth2AccessToken existingAccessToken = tokenStore
            .getAccessToken(authentication);
    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = null;
    if (existingAccessToken != null && existingAccessToken.isExpired()) {
        if (existingAccessToken.getRefreshToken() != null) {
            refreshToken = existingAccessToken.getRefreshToken();
            tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        }
        tokenStore.removeAccessToken(existingAccessToken);
    }

    refreshToken = createRefreshToken(authentication);
    final ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken expiring = (ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken) refreshToken;
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > expiring.getExpiration().getTime()) {
        refreshToken = createRefreshToken(authentication);
    }

    final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = createAccessToken(authentication, refreshToken);
    tokenStore.storeAccessToken(accessToken, authentication);
    refreshToken = accessToken.getRefreshToken();
    if (refreshToken != null) {
        tokenStore.storeRefreshToken(refreshToken, authentication);
    }
    return accessToken;

}

@Override
public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(final String accessTokenValue) {
    final DefaultOAuth2AccessToken accessToken = (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) tokenStore
            .readAccessToken(accessTokenValue);
    if (accessToken == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid access token: " + accessTokenValue);
    } else if (accessToken.isExpired()) {
        tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Access token expired: " + accessTokenValue);
    }

    final OAuth2Authentication result = tokenStore
            .readAuthentication(accessToken);

    if (clientDetailsService != null) {
        final String clientId = result.getOAuth2Request().getClientId();
        try {
            clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientId);
        } catch (final ClientRegistrationException e) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Client not valid: " + clientId, e);
        }
    }
    final int validitySeconds = getAccessTokenValiditySeconds(result
            .getOAuth2Request());
    accessToken
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + validitySeconds * 1000L));
    return result;
}

private ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken createRefreshToken(final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    if (!isSupportRefreshToken(authentication.getOAuth2Request())) {
        return null;
    }
    final int validitySeconds = getRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(authentication
            .getOAuth2Request());
    final ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = new DefaultExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken(UUID
            .randomUUID().toString(), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + validitySeconds * 1000L));
    return refreshToken;
}

private OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(final OAuth2Authentication authentication, final OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken) {
    final DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(UUID
            .randomUUID().toString());
    final int validitySeconds = getAccessTokenValiditySeconds(authentication
            .getOAuth2Request());
    if (validitySeconds > 0) {
        token.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + validitySeconds * 1000L));
    }
    token.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
    token.setScope(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getScope());

    return accessTokenEnhancer != null ? accessTokenEnhancer
            .enhance(token, authentication) : token;
}

@Override
public void setTokenEnhancer(final TokenEnhancer accessTokenEnhancer) {
    this.accessTokenEnhancer = accessTokenEnhancer;
}

@Override
public void setTokenStore(final TokenStore tokenStore) {
    this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
}

@Override
public void setClientDetailsService(final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
    this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
}

}
```

How I said at the beginning: I started from an other working copy of configuration, and transformed to the needs of this application.
It is also possible that I confused a little bit some config.

I repeat the at the end I would utilize the `OAUTH2` system to generate a token and utilize this token to authenticate the users. This authentication is made at with `/api/auth` (or `/api/secure/auth`?), the resources are available under `/api/secure` only for user with a valid token and other resources are available under `/api/yyy` and if they have a token more info is returned

When I run the test to try to make take a resource I receive this error:

```
 Body = {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Access is denied"}
```

Now I don't know exactely where I have to operate. In the security-context.xml or add some class to check the token.

Answer (score 1):

The Exception

```
Body = {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."}
```

Is actually related to `AuthTest` test class where the WebApplicationContext doesn't contain the filter chain for the Spring Security. You need to make the following changes for your `AuthTest` test class.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SalustroApplication.class)
public class AuthTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    // Inject this
    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {
        ResultActions doLogin = doLogin();
        assertEquals(doLogin.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(), "A valid Token");
    }

    protected ResultActions doLogin() throws Exception {
        DefaultMockMvcBuilder webAppContextSetup = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain); // Add filter
        MockMvc build = webAppContextSetup.build();

        final ResultActions loginResult = build.perform(post("/api/auth").param("grant_type", "password")
                .param("client_id", "testId").param("client_secret", "testSecret").param("username", "aUserName")
                .param("password", "123456").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print());

        return loginResult;

    }
}
```

Comment: Txs man. This helped me to go away from this error. Now I have other error. But why I have to do this?

Comment: Hi I have corrected the sources and the error. Now the problems is after I have made login, i become a access_token, but I don't know where I have to validate the token.